# Question related to the definition of accumulation point and Bolzano Weierstrass theorem

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification

I think I dont understand what a limit point of a set is. For example, there are two ways in which I have seen the BW theorem stated: 1. if the set $X$ is compact, then any sequence of points in X has a convergent subsequence. 2. Every subset with infinitely many points has a limit point. Perhaps I don't understand what the limit point means. The definition of limit point is that  a point $x_0$ is the limit point of $X$ if every neighborhood of $x_0$ contains infinitely many points of $X$. Does it also mean that every sequence in $X$ will converge to the limit point? I am little confused about these definitions. Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A limit point of $X$ is a limit of a sequence $x_n$ such as
$$
n\neq m\implies x_n\neq x_m
$$

Hence both definitions are equivalent because if $U\subset X$ has an infinite number of points, then you can put them in such a sequence; the sequence has a convergent subsequence iff $U$ has a limit point.

Comment: So any sequence $x_n$ converges to the limit point $x_0$, right?

Comment: no. Only a subsequence. There is the possibility of several possible limits, depending on the subsequence (for example: $x_n = (1-1/n)(-1)^n$: the odd indexes subsequence converges to -1, the even indexes subsequence converges to 1.